# Save adds return linebreaks to XML when elements are blank

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm loading a XML Document that has some tags that have no innertext.

If I populate the innertext with some data then it works as needed (you get opening tag, innertext and closing tag all on one line) like the following...

```xml
<element>value</element>
```

The problem arises with tags with no values. These SHOULD be displayed in the same way as above with the exception of no value of course, like the following:

```xml
<element></element>
```

However, when the innertext has an empty string it adds a carriage return & line feed which is not what is expected! It ends up looking like the following:

```xml
<element>
</element>
```

My code:

```bsh
$input_dir  = "F:\uma\zz"
$output_dir = "F:\uma\zz"
[xml]$xdoc  = Get-Content "$input_dir\Subnet_Network_41.xml"
$inprange   = 5
foreach ($i in $inprange) {
    $xdoc.Subnet.Id   = "Network_$i"
    $xdoc.Subnet.Name = "Network_$i"
    $xdoc.Save("$output_dir\Subnet_Network_$i.xml")
}
```

Comment: What does the original `Subnet_Network_41.xml` file look like?

Answer (score 3):

I have fixed the issue myself.  I have used `Select-xml`  to read the xml file and it worked. It didnt add the return linebreaks while saving the xml document. below is the working code.

```
$input_dir  = "F:\uma\zz"
$output_dir = "F:\uma\zz"
$xdoc = ( Select-Xml -Path $input_dir\Subnet_Network_41.xml -XPath / ).Node
$inprange   = 5
foreach ($i in $inprange) {
    $xdoc.Subnet.Id   = "Network_$i"
    $xdoc.Subnet.Name = "Network_$i"
    $xdoc.Save("$output_dir\Subnet_Network_$i.xml")
}
```

To know more about `Select-xml` refer the below blog:     https://blog.stangroome.com/2014/02/10/powershell-select-xml-versus-get-content/